# Find position of a body using physics formula

Tags: python

The question that I am being asked is:

> Using while and for loop,
>
> In    physics,    a   common  useful  equation    for finding the position    s   of  a   body
> in    linear  motion  at  a   given   time    t,  based   on  its initial position    s0, initial
> velocity  v0, and rate    of  acceleration    a,  is  the following:
>
> s=s0+v0t+1/2at^2
>
> Write a   program to  read    in  the initial position    s0, initial velocity    v0, and t
> (the  time    for moving) of  a   moving  body    from    users’  input.      Calculate   and
> print out the position    of  this    moving  body    within  time    range   of  [0, t].
> Where a = 9.8m/s/s

The problem is I know how to do the inputs and everything, but I have no idea how to do the loops for this question.

For output lets say the user inputed for t = 20, I am supposed to get a big output showing position s at every time from t=0 to t=20.

Comment: Do you know everything about `while` and `for` loops that is written [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#first-steps-towards-programming) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements)? If not, go ahead and work through the Python tutorial! If so, what exactly was the problem when you tried to write loops?

Comment: As a physical quantity, `t` should in principle be a floating-point number. But if you are only interested in integer values, then you could loop using `for t in range(21): do_stuff`. The calculations will still work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, yes I had a class on them and everything, I was able to do 5 more problems using while and for loops, but for some reason, I can't get my head around this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help you:

```
s = float(input('Initial position:'))
v = float(input('Initial velocity:'))
t = int(input('Time:'))
a = 9.8

for time in range(t+1):
    final_s = round(s + (v*time) + (0.5*a*time**2),2)
    print(f'Position at time = {time}s is {final_s}')
```

Output:

```
Initial position:5

Initial velocity:100

Time:20

Position at time = 0s is 5.0
Position at time = 1s is 109.9
Position at time = 2s is 224.6
Position at time = 3s is 349.1
Position at time = 4s is 483.4
Position at time = 5s is 627.5
Position at time = 6s is 781.4
Position at time = 7s is 945.1
Position at time = 8s is 1118.6
Position at time = 9s is 1301.9
Position at time = 10s is 1495.0
Position at time = 11s is 1697.9
Position at time = 12s is 1910.6
Position at time = 13s is 2133.1
Position at time = 14s is 2365.4
Position at time = 15s is 2607.5
Position at time = 16s is 2859.4
Position at time = 17s is 3121.1
Position at time = 18s is 3392.6
Position at time = 19s is 3673.9
Position at time = 20s is 3965.0
```

This is how you do it using the `while` loop:

```
time = 0
while time <= t:
    final_s = round(s + (v*time) + (0.5*a*time**2),2)
    print(f'Position at time = {time}s is {final_s}')
    time+=1
```

Just use this loop instead of the `for` loop.

Answer (score 2):

```
for t in range(time + 1):
    s = s0 + v0 * t + 0.5 * a * t**2
    print('t: {} s, position: {:.2f} m'.format(t, s))
```

For example

```
>>> time = 20
>>> s0 = 3.0
>>> v0 = 2.0
>>> a = 9.8
```

will output

```
time: 0 s, position: 3.00 m
time: 1 s, position: 9.90 m
time: 2 s, position: 26.60 m
time: 3 s, position: 53.10 m
time: 4 s, position: 89.40 m
time: 5 s, position: 135.50 m
time: 6 s, position: 191.40 m
time: 7 s, position: 257.10 m
time: 8 s, position: 332.60 m
time: 9 s, position: 417.90 m
time: 10 s, position: 513.00 m
time: 11 s, position: 617.90 m
time: 12 s, position: 732.60 m
time: 13 s, position: 857.10 m
time: 14 s, position: 991.40 m
time: 15 s, position: 1135.50 m
time: 16 s, position: 1289.40 m
time: 17 s, position: 1453.10 m
time: 18 s, position: 1626.60 m
time: 19 s, position: 1809.90 m
time: 20 s, position: 2003.00 m
```